# View User Info using Modal in laravel + vuejs

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-5.6

Can someone help me with this? 
I'm new to vuejs and have problem using modal in vuejs. 
My problem is clicking the button show user, the modal is not popping out.

Here is my ShowUser vue component

```
<template>

    <div class="modal fade" v-bind:class="{ 'is-active':modalState }">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                    ...
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                            </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

This is the script from ShowUser Vue Component

```
<script>

export default {
    name: "ShowUser",
    props: ['id'],
    data(){
        return {
            modalState: false
        }
    },

    created() {
        axios.get('/api/user/' + this.id).then(response => {
            console.log(response)
        })
    },
    methods: {
        handleActionButton() {
            this.modalState = true
        },
    }


}
```

This is the Users.vue

```
<template slot="actions" slot-scope="props">
   <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm fa fa-eye" @click="handleActionButton"></button>
   <ShowUser></ShowUser>
</template>
```

This is the index.js router

```
import ShowUser from '../views/setup/users/ShowUser'

export default new Router ({
routes : [
  {
    path: 'users/:id',
    name: 'ShowUser',
    component: ShowUser,
    props: true   
 }
]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `data-target` to toggle your modal:

**User.vue**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm fa fa-eye" 
        data-toggle="modal" 
        data-target="#myModal"
        @click="handleActionButton">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
```

**ShowUser**

```
<template>

    <div class="modal fade" 
         v-bind:class="{ 'is-active':modalState }" 
         id="myModal">
    </div>

</template>
```

Or you can [toggle modal by Javascript](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#via-javascript)

```
handleActionButton() {
  $('#myModal').modal('show')
  this.modalState = true
}
```